# Array Value keeps adding calculated value to previous value of array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

my array keeps adding the previous value of the array to the value can anyone help out to solve this i need just the calculated value not the previous value added to it

here's the portion of my code that calculates and sorts the value:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
        {

            angle = random_angle(angle, STEP_SIZE);


            // Compute the initial speed, using the selected angle.
            xspeed = INITSPEED * cos(2 * PI * angle / 360.0);
            yspeed = INITSPEED * sin(2 * PI * angle / 360.0);

            //Look up windspeed
            if (beaufort == 6)
            {
                wind = random_speed(STRONG_BREEZE_LO, STRONG_BREEZE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
                wave = random_wave(B6_WAVE_LO, B6_WAVE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
            }
            else if (beaufort == 5)
            {
                wind = random_speed(FRESH_BREEZE_LO, FRESH_BREEZE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
                wave = random_wave(B5_WAVE_LO, B5_WAVE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
            }
            else if (beaufort == 4)
            {
                wind = random_speed(MODERATE_BREEZE_LO, MODERATE_BREEZE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
                wave = random_wave(B4_WAVE_LO, B4_WAVE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
            }
            else if (beaufort == 3)
            {
                wind = random_speed(GENTLE_BREEZE_LO, GENTLE_BREEZE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
                wave = random_wave(B3_WAVE_LO, B3_WAVE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
            }
            else if (beaufort == 2)
            {
                wind = random_speed(LIGHT_BREEZE_LO, LIGHT_BREEZE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
                wave = random_wave(B2_WAVE_LO, B2_WAVE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
            }
            else if (beaufort == 1)
            {
                wind = random_speed(LIGHT_AIR_LO, LIGHT_AIR_HI, STEP_SIZE);
                wave = random_wave(B1_WAVE_LO, B1_WAVE_HI, STEP_SIZE);
            }
            else
            {
                wind = random_speed(CALM_LO, CALM_HI, STEP_SIZE);
            }

            //Repeat the following, as long a the y-position is greater than equal to wave height or the speed in y-direction is positive
            while(ycoord >= wave || yspeed >= 0)
            {
                //Compute the new positions
                xcoord = xcoord + xspeed * DELTA_T;
                ycoord = ycoord + yspeed * DELTA_T;
                //Compute new speeds
                xspeed = xspeed - DELTA_T * DRAG * (xspeed + wind);
                yspeed = yspeed - DELTA_T * GRAVITY - DELTA_T * DRAG * yspeed;
            }

            array[i] = xcoord;        
        }
```

Comment: try using a debugger...

Comment: There isn't enough information here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: what more information do you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
 xcoord = xcoord + xspeed * DELTA_T;
```

You are adding the previous value to the calculated value here

```
 array[i] = xcoord;
```

And then u assign to the array.

You might be missing steps to reset the xcoord/ycoord etc

Comment: could you help me out in getting the steps of fix that

Comment: write `xcoord = ycoord = 0;` before the `while` loop. In fact it would be better to have `int xcoord = 0; int ycoord = 0;` and remove whatever declaration you had outside the loop.

Comment: @user130824 you can follow Matt's suggestion. I concur that the 2nd solution is better